# Create a Google Form that responses go into a specific column on an existing spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have an existing Google Sheet which I would like to create a form for so users can input data more easily.

The form would have three questions and I would like them to go into their corresponding columns on the existing spreadsheet.

Question 1 would go into Column 1, Question 2 would go into Column 3 on the same row and Question 3 would go into Column 5 on the same row.

Does anyone know how I can do this or an Apps script for this please?

Comment: Just link the form and move the columns where you're expecting - shouldn't need a script for this.

Comment: @ross - easier said than done.... Below answer works very well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The easiest way to link the form to your existing spreadsheet

- Create a new form by going to https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/?tgif=d
- Click on "+"
- Populate your form questions as desired
- Click on "Responses"
- Click on the three vertical dots and "Select response destination"

On each form submitting the responses will automatically go into your spreadsheet - most likely into a new sheet created automatically.

### To move  form responses from the new sheet into the already existing sheet into specified columns

- Bind to your  destination spreadsheet a script with an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `onFormSubmit` trigger
- `onFormSubmit` retrieve the newest response with the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) `namedValues`
- assign the values individually to the last row of the desired columns in your sheet of  interest

*Sample:*

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var mySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("PASTE HERE THE SHEET NAME");
  var freeRow = (mySheet.getLastRow()+1);
  var column1 = 1;
  var column3 = 3;
  var column5 = 5;
// replace the following question titles by your real question titles
  mySheet.getRange(freeRow, column1).setValue(e.namedValues["What is your name?"]);
  mySheet.getRange(freeRow, column3).setValue(e.namedValues["How old are you?"]);
  mySheet.getRange(freeRow, column5).setValue(e.namedValues["Do you like Apps Script?"]);
}
```